Run Docker with same user as on local host and own mounted folders
I have a local folder (code) on my system, which belongs to my user.
The local folder path is something like this:
- home
-- my_user
---- work
------ projects
-------- code

I want to run a Docker container and mount this folder in the container. I want this mounted folder to belong to the user I have on the local host, so I can access files, create them inside the container, and still own them on the local host.
Docker is running in rootless mode.
I'm using this Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu

ARG UID
ARG GID
ARG USERNAME

# Install necessary packages including python3-virtualenv and pip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    wget \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-virtualenv \
    python3-dev \
    build-essential \
    git
RUN ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python && \
    ln -sf /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip

# Create a group with the specified GID
RUN groupadd -g ${GID} ${USERNAME}
# Create a user with the specified UID and GID (-d creates home folder, -s selects shell)
RUN useradd -d /home/${USERNAME} -u ${UID} -g ${GID} -s /bin/bash ${USERNAME}
# Add the user to the sudoers file
RUN echo "${USERNAME} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
RUN mkdir /home/${USERNAME}/code && chown ${USERNAME} /home/${USERNAME}/code
RUN echo "${USERNAME}"
USER ${USERNAME}

I'm building the image with:
docker build --build-arg UID=$(id -u) --build-arg GID=$(id -g) --build-arg USERNAME=$(whoami) -t image_name -f Dockerfile .

And running it with:
docker run -it -v /home/my_user/work/projects/code/:/home/my_user/code image_name

Inside the container, my username, id and gid are the same as on the local host.
However, if I check the permissions, I see that the code folder still belongs to root:
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 10 root root 4096 Jul 11 14:41 code

I tried running chown again from the container:
chown -R my_user code/

but I get:
chown: changing ownership of 'code/xxx': Operation not permitted

for all the files in the code folder.

I guess this happens because the folder is getting replaced by the folder in your system. Since the username or group of the folder in your system doesn't exist in the system, it is choosing the group ID and User ID of the folder in the system. So you might need to use an entrypoint.sh file to change the ownership while running the container.

Also, use -R flag in the chown command to reflect the subfolders and files inside the folder.
